# Using the filter or find method to retrieve an object inside a json

Tags: json, typescript, filter, find, angular5

How can I obtain one of these objects by using the filter or find method and looking for a match inside of the **fiberAgrupations** Array

I tried doing this:

```
const landlineRate = this.monolineJsonRates[0].cambioCaudal.getAll()
    .filter(landlinedRates => landlinedRates["fiberAgrupations"].includes(this.myPackId));
```

**myPackId** is 3230 which is in the first object.

**JSON**:

```
         [{
            "id": "T300Mb2",
            "idAdditionalImage": "",
            "name": "300 Mb",
            "sourceId": ["T300Mb2"],
            "fiberAgrupations": ["3230","3232","3234","3235","3237","3239","3248","3250","2875","2877","3139","3140","3074","3075"],
            "prices": [
              {"id": "3149", "price": "34,95"},
              {"id": "3156", "price": "39,95"},
            ],
            "availableRates": ["T600Mb2", "T1Gb"]
         },
         {
            "id": "T600Mb",
            "idAdditionalImage": "",
            "name": "600 Mb",
            "sourceId": ["T600Mb"],
            "fiberAgrupations": ["2989","2994","2982","2983","3090","3089","3093","3084","2875","2877","3139","3140","3074","3075"],
            "prices": [
              {"id": "3149", "price": "38,95"},
              {"id": "3156", "price": "47,95"},
            ],
            "availableRates": []
         },
         {
            "id": "T600Mb2",
            "idAdditionalImage": "",
            "name": "600 Mb",
            "sourceId": ["T600Mb2"],
            "fiberAgrupations": ["3219","3220","3223","3224","3241","3244","3252","3255","2875","2877","3139","3140","3074","3075"],
            "prices": [
              {"id": "3149", "price": "38,95"},
              {"id": "3156", "price": "43,95"},
            ],
            "availableRates": ["T1Gb"]
         }],
```

Answer (score 1):

**Find** will give you first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function.
**Filter** will give you a new array with all elements in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function.

Simplified:

```
const rates = [{
    'id': 'T300Mb2',
    'fiberAgrupations': ['3230', '3232']
  },
  {
    'id': 'T600Mb',
    'fiberAgrupations': ['2989', '2994']
  },
  {
    'id': 'T600Mb2',
    'fiberAgrupations': ['3219', '3220'],
  }];

const myPackId = '3230';
const result = rates.filter(landlinedRates =>
 landlinedRates['fiberAgrupations'].includes(myPackId)
);
console.log(result);
```

gives:

```
[ 
   { 
    id: 'T300Mb2', 
    fiberAgrupations: [ '3230', '3232' ]
   } 
]
```

Comment: This returns an empty array just like the solution I tried myself

Comment: Are u sure the `getAll` method is returning the results? Can it be that the getAll function is an async function?

Comment: My JSON wasnt being deserialized correctly... my solution does work, sorry for the mess up